# Postgresql: Aggregate Based on the Number of Times an item appeared on a column

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I've been having trouble looking for this. Is there an easier way of doing this?

| person | city | industry |
| --- | --- | --- |
| mark | tokyo | IT |
| mark | tokyo | Retail |
| mark | sydney | IT |
| chad | london | Marketing |
| chad | new york | IT |
| chad | new york | Marketing |

Desired output: Need to have this aggregated based on the number of times the item in the column appears. All grouped by person

| person | city | industry |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mark | tokyo | IT |
| chad | new york | Marketing |

Is there an easier/more efficient way rather than doing a count > rank > select where rank = 1?
Because I tried doing that but i have to rejoin everything to **person**. I have a lot of columns to deal with so I'm trying to find an easier way.

Comment: "but i have to rejoin everything to person" - why is that a bad thing? You should `JOIN` as-late-as-possible (or as-outer-as-possible) to avoid carrying-over redundant data - and to _signal intent_ to the DBMS' query plan-builder so it can potentially generate a better plan.

Comment: "Need to have this aggregated based on the number of times the item in the column appears." - you haven't told us how to aggregate "**this**", nor have you told us **which** column you're referring to.

Comment: Would need to group by person. the city and industry output would be based on how many counts of the item appeared in the table. For example: Mark: tokyo appeared twice on the table, so the final output for his city is Tokyo. as for Industry, it would be IT because it appeared twice as well

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.person,
       ( array_agg(city order by cnt_city desc) )[1] as city,
       ( array_agg(industry order by cnt_industry desc) )[1] as industry
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by person, city) as cnt_city,
             count(*) over (partition by person, industry) as cnt_industry
      from t
     ) t
group by t.person;
```

Or, alternatively, `distinct on` with aggregation for each column:

```
select *
from (select distinct on (person) person, city
      from t
      group by person, city
      order by person, order by count(*) desc
     ) c join
     (select distinct on (person) person, industry
      from t
      group by person, industry
      order by person, order by count(*) desc
     ) i
     using (person);
```

Redshift supports neither `distinct on` nor arrays.  So, instead:

```
select *
from (select person, city,
             row_number() over (partition by person order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by person, city
     ) c join
     (select person, industry,
             row_number() over (partition by person order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by person, industry
     ) i
     using (person)
where c.seqnum = 1 and i.seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: seems like this won't work for me because i'm using redshift. My bad to assume that postgresql and redshift is exactly the same

Comment: @hahahahahelp How is it "not working" for you, exactly?

Comment: @hahahahahelp . . . Tag your questions correctly:  Redshift is not Postgres.  I fixed the tag and added an alternative answer.